# How can I retrieve elements from an IBMdb2 database?

Tags: python, flask, db2

This is my current code

```
    email = request.args.get('email')
    password = request.args.get('password')
    sql = 'SELECT email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?'
    stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql)
    param = email
    email = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt, param)
    print(email)
```

It always returns an error and I can't get the values I need from my db2 database. What should I do to make it work?

my error code is

```
line 29, in login
    email = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)
Exception: Fetch Failure: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0125E  Function sequence error. SQLSTATE=HY010 SQLCODE=-99999
```

Comment: When you ask for help, never write "returns an error", instead give the full exact error message/error code.   Your code presumes that the table USUARIOS exists in the same schema as the currently connected user (it may, or may not exist there) . Also your code fails to bind a value for the email parameter , and also fails to execute the prepared statement.  Please study some examples. Always use an exception handler.

Comment: Examples of prepare, bind etc are here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054696.html

Comment: You got the CLI0125E error because you cannot run fetch_assoc unless you previously ran a bind_param() followed by an execute().

Comment: I added the error. This is my first time using bd2 and the docs are so confusing. This code is what I copy pasted from them. I'm still a bit confused. What should I do?

Comment: Yeah I used bind_param() and execute, my code works perfectly now, thx

Comment: Consider marking answers as correct or upvoting when you get answers or help

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question missed out required steps:

- ibm_db.bind_param() to give a value to the parameter marker
- ibm_db.execute() to execute the prepared statement with the bound value

When there is an unexpected sequence (for example a missing API, in this case a fetch before any previous execute) then the driver will return CLI0125E (function sequence error).

Example code is in the [Db2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054696.html) and many other places online.

It is wise to use exception handlers ( a `try:` ... `except:` block) in the code to catch and handle errors.